# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to insert some data into MySQL database (model LogsSeparate) through Django and Django Rest Framework but I keep getting an error which I bet is very easy to solve yet I couldn't figure it out myself:

Error:

> if obj.pk is None:
>
> AttributeError: 'LogObjTest' object has no attribute 'pk'

Code:

```py
class LogObjTest():          
    def __init__(self):   
        self._id = None  
        self.bits = None  
class getLogs(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    arrayTest=[]
    for x in Logs.objects.all():        
        serializer_class = LogsSeparateSerializer
        test = Fields.objects.filter(pac_id=x.message_id_decimal)
        binaryTest=x.data_binary
        
        for i in test:
            obj=LogObjTest()
            obj._id=x.message_id_decimal
            obj.bits=binaryTest[i.fld_offset:i.fld_offset+i.fld_len]
            arrayTest.append(obj)
            
 
        queryset = arrayTest
        LogsSeparate.objects.bulk_create(arrayTest)

    print("arrayTest",arrayTest)
```

models.py

````
class LogsSeparate(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, null=False, db_column='_id')
    bits = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_column='bits')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bits```
````

Comment: `LogObjTest` is not a model...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, the models.py is: 
```
class LogsSeparate(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, null=False, db_column='_id')
    bits = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_column='bits')```

Comment: then why do you not use that model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `LogObjTest`. Import `LogsSeparate` that you created in the model.py file then use it to create a new object.

```py
class getLogs(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    arrayTest=[]
    for x in Logs.objects.all():        
        serializer_class = LogsSeparateSerializer
        test = Fields.objects.filter(pac_id=x.message_id_decimal)
        binaryTest=x.data_binary
        
        for i in test:
            obj=LogsSeparate(_id=x.message_id_decimal, bits=binaryTest[i.fld_offset:i.fld_offset+i.fld_len])
            arrayTest.append(obj)
            
 
        queryset = arrayTest
        LogsSeparate.objects.bulk_create(arrayTest)

    print("arrayTest",arrayTest)
```

Comment: Thanks to you and to @Willem Van Onsem. It's working now!